# Hyper-V VM bluescreens upon LiveMotioning

Tags: hyper-v, bsod

I am doing some testing with Hyper-V LiveMotion, and when I stress the VM and try to LiveMotion it, sometimes it'll work just fine, sometimes it'll restart and give no clear error, sometimes it just "fails" and I have to manually restart the VM.

The most common error though is a bluescreen in the actual VM. It's a 0x00000124 error with no clear indication of what could be wrong. Googling it just gives some hits with bluescreens apparently related to audio drivers, but those can't be a problem in this case, right?

I run Hyper-V RC2 on a full Enterprise installation. Processors are pretty much the same (Theyre both AMD Barcelona machines, one 2-way and the other 4-way but both just have 2 CPU's). Instruction set and stepping and what not are exactly the same.

Can anyone think of a solution, maybe someone who experienced the same and can tell me if there's something specific triggering this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the latest BIOS and drivers (esp. network)?  STOP 0x000000124 indicates an uncorrectable error from WHEA (Windows Hardware Error Architecture) and strongly points to hardware issues.

Comment: My internship ended and sadly I have not managed to find the problem. It was weird though because both my machines would sometimes hang (no apparent reason, no bluescreen, nothing in even log), sometimes the VM would hang with the bluescreen I mentioned (and I saw 1 more bluescreen, think that one had error code 0x00000007 but im not sure)

can a hardware or possibly driver/bios error cause a VM to bluescreen? I'd think it'd make the actual machine crash instead...

Answer (score 1):

Because Hyper-V uses a hypervisor it is very sensitive to faults with the underlying hardware, especially the BIOS.  I would expect the host machine to crash, but you never know.  Or, if the two host machines are not in sync, that can certainly do it, as LiveMotion would be very sensitive to differences.  Or, it could just be a bug, after all it is still an RC.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let me get you started on the reputation part...